# R readBin skip after every value

Tags: r, binary, skip

I have a matlab-File, that reads in a lot of binary data and I want to do that with an R-programm. My question is, if there is a command in R that allows me to read many values, but after reading in each value, it skips a certain amount of bytes before reading the next value?
In matlab is the function "fread" which has this feature. For example:

```
A = fread(fileID,sizeA,precision,skip)

tmp = fread(fid,1219704,'double',42);
```

This reads in 1,219,704 double values of 8 byte and after reading **each** value skips 42 byte.

In r I am trying this right now:

```
tmp = vector()
for(k in 1:1219704)
{
   tmp2 = readBin(fid, double(), size=8, endian="little")
   tmp = c(tmp,tmp2)
   seek(fid,42,"current")
}
```

My idea was to create a loop that reads in every single double value one by one of the total 1,219,704 double values, adding it to the vector *tmp* and then skip 42 bytes with the seek function. But this takes soooo long. Is there another way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: R as a function `fread` in the `data.table` package. Does that help you ?

Comment: No, because this `fread` reads in a table and not binary data.

Comment: I know this was 7 years ago, but... did you ever figure it out? I have the exact same issue right now.